# Problem with `pause` command when redirecting a command-line log to file

Tags: windows-7, command-line, redirect, input

Let's say we execute a command as below and redirect the console output into text file.

My issue is that there is `pause` commands within the batch script and when redirecting like this, I cannot know when to hit enter to continue the batch.

Please help me to get the batch "ignores" the `pause` commands without changing the batch itself. I prefer to get some redirect/pipe syntax.

```
MyBatchScriptWithPause.bat > SomeFile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 (echo.&echo.&echo.&echo.) | MyBatchScriptWithPause.bat > somefile.txt
```

assuming that no other command is expecting user input in that batch file.

**Edit**
It also assumes that only a *single* `pause` command is in that file. Otherwise Andriy's suggestion should work.

Comment: The OP says: *'`pause` **commands**'*. I think, instead of `echo x` it might be `type file.txt` where `file.txt` is a file with umpteen empty lines.

Comment: Although `(echo.&echo.&echo.&echo.)|MyBatchScriptWithPause.bat > somefile.txt` might work too.

Comment: Chosen as accepted answer.Please update your answer to include `(echo.&echo.&echo.&echo.)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
MyBatchScriptWithPause.bat > SomeFile.txt < nul
```

`nul` is a DOS device that will provide infinite null data, so it will act as input whenever the script needs some. It is still available even on modern Windows versions.

Comment: This is promising. I'll check it. Thanks @mrb.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about ignoring the pauses, but you could redirect them to standard error:

```
pause 1>&2
```

which would allow you to know when a pause had occurred.

Comment: Thanks Paul. But I don't want to change to pause calls currently in batch file.